# Incomplete HTTP_REQUEST after synchronous HttpReceiveHttpRequest

Tags: winapi, httpserver

I'm getting an "incomplete" `HTTP_REQUEST` when calling `HttpReceiveHttpRequest` in synchronous mode (i.e., `pOverlapped = NULL`) and a complete one if I instead wait, say, 100 milliseconds, before reading the structure.

For instance, `HTTP_COOKED_URL` has a `FullUrlLength` of 52 but all the 52 bytes pointed by `pFullUrl` are zero. However, if I wait some time after calling `HttpReceiveHttpRequest`, the returned structure is complete, meaning that the `FullUrl` as well as the rest of the fields come with data.

I've tried with both `HTTP_RECEIVE_REQUEST_FLAG_FLUSH_BODY` and `HTTP_RECEIVE_REQUEST_FLAG_COPY_BODY`.

Is this behavior normal or unexpected?

Comment: I've never used this function so I can't answer this question but after reading the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) two questions occur to me. 1. What value is returned by the function and 2. what value is pointed to be the pBytesReceived argument.

Comment: I get the same regardless of whether the structure is complete or not: 0 as the return value and e.g. 826 bytes, depending on the browser I use to send the request. BTW I'm issuing `http://localhost:50000/tp/` from the web browser to generate the request.

Comment: Have you looked at this sample (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? The sample seems to be very similiar to what you are trying to do. It uses HttpReceiveHttpRequest in synchronous modem, so it would be interesting to see whether it behaves the same way as your code.

Comment: StackOverflow has some guidelines on how to ask questions, and you might get more answers to your question of you followed these guidelines (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Stuart Thanks for suggesting the reading of how-to-ask. I will follow you advice.